# Chaincode instantiate fails?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I create a chaincode and It was Install on all the peers successfully. But when I try to instantiate it failed with giving me an error.This is the error which I got.

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1
>   Instantiate chaincode Failed....

This is peer logs.

> 2019-05-07 11:47:55.307 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 17d [myc][9db7acfb] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 1
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
>           /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
>   runtime.goexit
>           /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
>   chaincode registration failed
>   2019-05-07 11:47:55.316 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 17e unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.22.0.21:43758 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=11.3317712s

But when I try with this using fabcar chaincode which was provided with fabric-samples It was Instantiated successfully. I tried a lot to find out a solution to this problem but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this problem? .Thank you.

Comment: including the the chaincode (or at least the important part of it) may be helpful.

Comment: can you attach chaincode logs?

Comment: @ArtemBarger Chaincode container is disappearing just after created. And Even when I hit `docker ps -a` it is not available there as exited container.

Comment: Try to compile your chaincode

Comment: @ArtemBarger Can you guide me to do so? Because I am new to this Hyperledger fabric world.